# Exporting training data for deep learning in ArcGIS Pro with a fixed buffer area around each polygon

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, deep-learning

I have a raster image with building polygons and I want to use these to extract data for deep learning using the ArcGIS Pro [tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/image-analyst/export-training-data-for-deep-learning.htm).

I would like to have a single polygon per image and therefore I'm using the "Labeled Tiles" format.

Additionally, I would like to have a fixed buffer area around each polygon. I don't think the "Fixed Crops" option does this because it crops a fixed size image regardless of the size of the polygon. What I want is to have all the polygon in the image with an added buffer zone around the polygon similarly to what's shown in the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an idea, so untested. The Export Training Data For Deep Learning has the parameter *input_mask_polygons* may be you can create your *Bounding mask*?

You could create the your bounding boxes by first using the [Minimum Bounding Geometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm) tool then buffer out by 15m. It's that buffered datasets that you supply into the *input_mask_polygons* parameter.

Comment: Hello, thanks for proposing, it seems like the way to go. I've prepared the buffered dataset as you suggested however I cannot get the *Export Training Data* to work as I intend.

I want each buffered bounding box to be exported into one image and a metadata file containing the object class and the box coordinates.

However, it seems to ignore *input_mask_polygons* and generate chips based on the *Tile Size X* and *Tile Size Y*.

Can you suggest proper settings for the *Export Training Data* tool?

Comment: No, I've not used that parameter before and I too am learning on the job with the new deep learning tools.  So if it does not work you need to contact ESRI directly and see if they can offer up a reason why?

Comment: I've managed to make it work. You just provide your buffered polygons as your *Input Feature Class* and don't use *Input Mask Polygons*.